# create animated charts and render it to png image sequence or swf file

Tags: flash, charts

Is there a way create a animated charts in png sequence or swf files so that I can embed that in video editing software? 
I use c# .net to create a client application. It polls data periodically from server. Now the goal is to create charts and save it as a PNG sequence(or just a simple PNG image) based on that data.

I've completed polling part of the application. I'm stuck in creating charts and saving it as a file.

Comment: Recommending tools is explicitly outside of SO's scope. See [ask], then do some background work.

Comment: Used Sync fusion charts that exports a image
https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/classic-chart/how-to/export-sfchart-as-image